# How to create a user in Prisma database on firebase auth sign up?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, nestjs, prisma

I want to use firebase auth for handling authentication in my React native app, but I already have a REST API implemented in NestJS using prisma as an ORM. Is there a way to create users in my own database when using firebase auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be through Cloud Functions, which can be triggered when a [user is created](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation). From your implementation of that Cloud Function you'd then call your own REST API to add the user to your database.